# Show that $A_{4}$ has no subgroup of order $6$

Tags: group-theory

I have a few questions on the following proof:

We claim there are no subgroups of order 6. Any such subgroup must contain some elements of order $3$ (since there are only $4$ other elements)$^{*1}$, and these come in inverse pairs. So any subgroup $H$ of order $6$ must contain the identity$^{*2}$, either $2$ or $4$ elements of order $3$, and either $3$ or $1$ elements of order $2$.$^{*3}$ After renumbering$^{*4}$, we may therefore assume that $(1 2 3) \in H$ and $(1 2)(3 4) \in H$. But then H must contain $$(1 2 3)(1 2)(3 4) = (1 3 4);$$ together with its inverse $(1 4 3)$, and must also contain $$(1 2)(3 4)(1 2 3) = (2 4 3);$$ together with its inverse $(2 3 4)$. This gives at least $3$ pairs of elements of order $2$, together with the identity, so that $H$ contains at least $7$ elements. This is impossible, so $A_{4}$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

$^{*1}$ Why must any such subgroup contain some elements of order 3?

$^{*2}$ I'm assuming the order doesn't effect it any way?

$^{*3}$ Where are these numbers from (I understand they must add up to the order - 6)?

$^{*4}$ What does it mean by renumbering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$. Suppose there were a subgroup of order $6$, say $H$. $H$ clearly cannot be generated by a single element. So there are no elements of order $6$. Since the elements in $H$ cannot all have order $1$ and it still must have $6$ elements, the only possibility is that the elements of $H$ have order $2$ or order $3$. Since $A_4$ has only $3$ elements of order $2$, clearly $H$ must contain at least one element of the form $(abc)$ .

$2$. Not quite sure what you are asking but if I understand your question correctly, no, the order does not matter.

$3$. Yes, it must total to $6$ elements. In any case, it must include the identity. That leaves $5$ elements. Then you have two cases depending on which type of element you assume $H$ has. The two cases are $2$ elements of order $3$ and $3$ elements of order $2$ or $4$ elements of order $3$ and $1$ element of order $2$.

$4.$ What it means is there is no way of knowing that $H$ contained $(123)$, maybe it was $(234)$. But just call what you originally called $2$ instead $1$, what you called $3$ instead $2$ and what you called $3$ instead $4$ (ie renumbering), and $H$ contains $(123)$ instead. So what you are doing is saying it doesn't matter what element in particular $H$ contains, i.e. $(123)$ or $(234)$ or $(142)$ etc, just so long as it contains one that 'looks like' $(abc)$. They just pick $(123)$ and run through the argument because if it were any other $3$-cycle, you could just renumber everything and it works just the same.

**EDIT**: There is a nice simple proof [here](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/4033/absalg17.pdf) (bottom of page $4$).

Comment: So we generate a subgroup $H$ with $|H| > 7$ elts., but how do we know that some $h$ is actually in $H$. For example, $h = (1 2)(3 4)$, we have put this into the subgroup since it is a possibility but surely to prove that $H$ is not possible, we must prove that each element is actually an element and not just a possibility?

Comment: Your comment is not clearly phrased. We know that $H$ must contain an element of order $2$ and order $3$. The proof just chooses such an element of order $2$ and $3$ and says you can always get the ones they chose after renumbering. Perhaps it would be a good learning exercise to choose a few others and see how renumbering gets you such elements. Though you could have chosen something like $(12)$ as an element of order $2$. The closure of $H$ will still produce too many elements to have order $6$. It's about showing that no matter what the choice, $H$ will have too many elements.

Comment: Ok so is this proof fairly long winded? Surely we can just say each $g \in A_{4}$ is a possibility so therefore the order of this subgroup would always be greater than $6$?

Comment: No, this proof is as short as it gets and is the standard proof that is always given. If the proof you are reading is confusing you, perhaps try the proof at the bottom of page $4$ in my answer that I linked. It is the same argument but I believe a bit cleaner. It gets to the heart of the issue--that not matter what $H$ contains, so long as $|H|=6$, the closure property of the subgroup forces it to have more than $6$ elements, clearly a contradiction.

Comment: I also like it more as it does not try to pick any particular element, such as $(123)$, it leaves it in full generality by choosing $(abc)$ or $(ab)(cd)$.